# Using ThreadPoolExecutor and connection pool without random blocking method call

Tags: java, connection-pooling, nonblocking, threadpoolexecutor

I've been using StackOverFlow for a long time now and always found existing answers, but this time I couldn't find any information about what I'm trying to do.

Using java, I have a process composed of about 10 different tasks that gather distinct data from the database using pure jdbc (no ejb/jpa here). Each task (callable) can actually be run concurrently and is responsible for obtaining a connection, which is what we are doing. However we're randomly experiencing trouble with the connection pool (accessed via jndi), sometimes we're blocked because the connection pool doesn't have any available connection.

To solve this problem, I thought we could change the way we're obtaining the connections, instead of letting each callable opening and closing a connection ( following the number of tasks to execute and the number of threads to use in the ThreadPoolExecutor), I would like to create some kind of local connections pool dedicated to this process, so that we're sure nothing will block later (eventually if we can't acquire all the requested connections, we would then adapt the number of threads to launch with a minimum of 1)

My colleagues approve this idea, but what surprises me is that I can't found any similar approaches or discussion on the web (maybe I'm not using the right keywords).

I would like to know what you think about this idea, whether you already tried something similar or if I'm missing something important.

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Is it common that all 10 tasks are running concurrently? If yes, do you really need them to? Couldn't you just limit the number of concurrent running threads on your thread pool, making sure you wouldn't get all the database connections from the connection pool? What I'm saying is that if you have 10 available connections but the maximum number of threads on your thread pool is, for instance, 3, you know that in the worst case you'll still have 7 connections left.

Comment: If each task is in each own thread, why do you need a per task pool? Just start the task with a connection and work with the same connection all the time.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula at the origin all the process was in a single method on a single thread, and this was very taking a very long time, a first optimization (not mine) added multithreading to this so that only the longest request would be limiting here, but they missed other details that are now fixed, but I think this still not correct. 

Using all connection from the server pool isn't a problem in itself, what matters here is to be sure that the different threads end properly (in this way we're sure connection will be available after this).

Comment: @JPMoresmau : i'm not sure if we can share safely a single connection in a multithreaded context (even if we're only doing select operation in my case)

I'll do some research about this

Comment: I mean use one connection per thread, of course threads should not share connections. Get the connections, open one thread per connection you can obtain, and work away.

Comment: Which is more or less what I explained in the question :) I'm rather wondering if the code I'm about to write doesn't already exist, but it doesn't seem to and either there's a good reason that I'm missing, or people who implemented this never shared this kind of solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned which connection pool is used. If it is not [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) and you are allowed to switch, having contributed there I recommend it.

Comment: Indeed, but Imho I tend to prefer portable code not depending on any specific implementation on the server side on which I don't have a full control. Your idea might work however, i'll have a look at hikariCP, but you didn't explained what would be the benefit using it

Comment: Picking well tested and mature library or tool is wiser option than to write your own considering 'concurrency is hard to get right' mostly. you can be up and running with very few parameters tuning to your need  and it is most 'portable' among popular pools. Link has more information, some good read in wiki there as well.

Answer (score 0):

HikariCP seems rather interesting finally, i'll have to check this further. But this isn't directly related to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little return of experience, my idea is working, with one caveat, I couldn't get rid of one downcast from a runnable to my implementation on which I can do .setConnection() during the before() of my ExecutorService. And all tasks must have been given to the executor with the execute() method, otherwise the runnable is autolatically wrapped in a FutureTask without the ability to access the inner runnable. Maybe one of you know of to do this correctly ?

Comment: Just one last add, I still need to do one small change to correctly manage connections that would be opened too late when the server would be too long to answer, at least we would have a single connection available, which is enough to start the executor service, by limiting it to the number of connection (only one at worst)